# Bash Script to Loop Through All Videos in a Folder on Raspbian Wheezy

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have the following bash script courtesy of [this post](http://www.cenolan.com/2013/03/looping-video-playlist-omxplayer-raspberry-pi/):

```
#!/bin/sh

# get rid of the cursor so we don't see it when videos are running
setterm -cursor off

# set here the path to the directory containing your videos
VIDEOPATH="/mnt/storage/videos" 

# you can normally leave this alone
SERVICE="omxplayer"

# now for our infinite loop!
while true; do
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
    then
        sleep 1;
    else
        for entry in $VIDEOPATH/*
        do
            clear
            omxplayer $entry > /dev/null
        done
    fi
 done
```

I have changed the call to omxplayer to full screen and output the sound so:

```
omxplayer -r -o hdmi $entry > /dev/null
```

But even before that change to my preferred settings the script only seems to play the first video in the folder which it loops over endlessly. I have checked the permission on the videos and they are all the same owned by the user who runs the script.

Comment: Have you tried adding debug output in the loop?

Comment: Rookie forgetfulness, no I haven't. I shall try some debug. Thanks.

Comment: when you say "only seems to play the first video in the folder", do you mean that "it repeats the first video over and over"?

Comment: Yes, it loops endlessly over the first video, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

That script is wrong. I have made some updates to it. See if that works for you

```
#!/bin/sh

# get rid of the cursor so we don't see it when videos are running
setterm -cursor off

# set here the path to the directory containing your videos
VIDEOPATH="/mnt/storage/videos" 

# you can normally leave this alone
SERVICE="omxplayer"

for entry in $VIDEOPATH/*
do
    clear
    $SERVICE $entry > /dev/null

    while ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
    do
        sleep 5;
    done
done
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. When I echoed the file name it only ran through one for me.

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it play any video? Remove the "> /dev/null" while you are troubleshooting.